# How can I use the value of a swift string as the name of an UIObject to edit?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to edit an UIObject with the value of a swift string?
If I for example have to change the backgroundcolor of a button created in the storyboard of a swift iOS project, and I cannot write the name, but that the name is the value of a string. Is it then possible to change the backgroundcolor of the button? The reason I'm trying to do this, is that I have a lot of buttons that calls a function with the parameter of their own name when pressed. When it's done the function knows which button to color red. I have tried something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var PressMeButtonOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func PressMeButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    reColor("PressMeButtonOutlet")
}    


func reColor (buttonName: String) {

\(buttonName).backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: You **don't**. Pass the `sender` along instead!

Answer (score 1):

When a UIButton triggers an `IBAction`, it sends its own reference as the sender.

So the easy way to do it is this:

```
@IBAction func PressMeButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    reColor(sender)
}    


func reColor (button: UIButton) {

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Notice that I have changed the IBAction parameter to `UIButton`.